# How can I tarball the proc file system?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I would like to take a snapshot of my entire proc file system, and save it in a tarball (or in the worst case concatenate all of the text files together into a single text file).

But when I run:

```
tar -c /proc
```

I get a segfault.

What's the best way to do this?  Should I set up some kind of recursive walk through each file?

I only have the basic *nix utilities, such as bash, cat, ls, echo, etc.  I don't have anything fancy like python or perl or java.

Comment: try `tar -vc /proc > /dev/null`, at which file the segfault is produced?

Comment: I really, really have to wonder why you want this.

Comment: Maybe ask over on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: "tar" froze when it got to /proc/kmsg

Comment: Another problem I've run into (while trying to tar a subset of `/proc`) is that some of the "files" have contents when you read them, but their directory entries indicate a size of 0. (One might argue that that's a bug.) For example, on my system `wc -c /proc/stat` gives a size of 1710 bytes, but `ls -l /proc/stat` shows a size of 0. `tar` (at least GNU tar) apparently pays attention to the size indicated by the directory entry and doesn't bother to read the data. `cp` does read the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linux /proc filesystem is actually kernel variables pretending to be a filesystem. There is nothing to save thus nothing to backup. If the system let you, you could `rm -rf /proc` and it would magically reappear upon the next reboot.

The /dev file system has real i-nodes and they can be backed up. Except they have no contents, just a major and minor number, permissions, and a name. Tools that do backup special device files only record those parameters and never try to open(2) the device. However, since the device major and minor numbers are only meaningful on the precise system they are built for, there is little cause for backing them up.

The reason that trying to tar the /proc pseudo-filesystem causes tar to segfault is because /proc has funny file behavior: things like a write-only pseudo-file may appear to have read permissions, but return an error indication if a program tries to open(2) it for backup. That's sure to drive a naïve tar to get persnickety.

### Added in response to comment

It doesn't surprise me that tar had problems reading /proc/kmsg because it has some funny properties:

```
# strace cat /proc/kmsg
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "kmsg"],
open("kmsg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)      = 3
// ok, no problem opening the file for reading
fstat64(3, { st_mode=S_IFREG|0400,  st_size=0,
// looks like a normal file of zero length
// but cat does not pay attention to st_size so it just
// does a blocking read
read(3, "<4>[103128.156051] ata2.00: qc t"..., 32768) = 461
write(1, "<4>[103128.156051] ata2.00: qc t"..., 461) = 461
// ...forever...
read(3, "<6>[103158.228444] ata2.00: conf"..., 32768) = 48
write(1, "<6>[103158.228444] ata2.00: conf"..., 48) = 48
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

Since /proc/kmsg is a running list of kernel messages as they happen, it never returns 0 (EOF) it just keeps going until I get bored and press ^C.

Interestingly, my tar has no trouble with /proc/kmsg:

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.22
# tar cf /tmp/junk.tar /proc/kmsg
$ tar tvf /tmp/junk.tar
-r-------- root/root         0 2010-09-01 14:41 proc/kmsg
```

and if you look at the strace output, GNU tar 1.22 saw that st_length == 0 and didn't even bother opening the file for reading, since there wasn't anything there.

I can imagine that your tar saw the length was 0, allocated that much (none) space using malloc(3) which dutifully handed back a pointer to a zero length buffer. Your tar read from /proc/kmsg, got a non-zero length read, and tried to store it in the zero length buffer and got a segmentation violation.

That is but one rat-hole that awaits tar in /proc. How many more are there? Dunno. Will they behave identically? Probably not. Which of the ~1000 or so files which aren't `/proc/<pid>` psuedo-files are going to have weird semantics? Dunno.

But perhaps the most telling question: What sense would you make of /proc/sys/vm/lowmem_reserve_ratio, will it be different next week, and will you be able to learn anything from that difference?

Comment: Good answer.  I'd add that `/sys` is the same sort of thing, kernel variables pretending to be a file system.  It shouldn't be backed up either.

Comment: I understand that the /proc file system is composed of virtual files (not actually present on the hard drive), but there are still a lot of files in there that I can read with "cat".  I would like to copy all of the files that are readable to a physical file system so that I may have a snapshot of what it looked like at one point in time.  Is there a single command (or a few commands) that I can use to accomplish this task without crashing?

Comment: It's somewhat minor, but by not having only /proc/ itself archived, I've had systems I've deployed my images to halt on boot. It's easy enough for me to manually make just /proc/ itself and then it'll boot.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer makes a lot of sense if you want to argue the sense of doing something like this, nevertheless there is an answer that works. Here's a script to duplicate the complete /proc file system into /tmp/proc. This can then be tarred and gzipped. I used this to keep a memory of the setup and capabilities (memory, bogomips, default processes, etc.) of my trusty old file server before I replaced it with a new one.

```
cd /
mkdir /tmp/proc
find /proc -type f | while read F ; do
   D=/tmp/$(dirname $F)
   test -d $D || mkdir -p $D
   test -f /tmp/$F || sudo cat $F > /tmp/$F
done
```

**Notes:**
Permissions are not preserved since I have to use `cat` instead of `cp`.
`cp -a /proc /proccopy` doesn't work since it crashes on "kcore" as well. mc (Midnight Commander) succeeds in creating a copy of /proc which you can then tar and gzip, but you have to dismiss thousands of "Cannot read file XYZ" errors and it too crashes on 'kcore' with a Bus Error.

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer:

```
ls -Rd /proc/* > proc.lst 
foreach item (<proc.lst>)
  echo "proc_file:$item"
  if (-f $item) cat $item
end
```

Apropos the site advisory protocol:

"But avoid ... Making statements based on opinion..."

(IMHO...based on quite a few years experience) It doesn't require much imagination to think of some good reasons for, at a given point in time, taking a snapshot of selected elements of /proc/* and storing it, or sending it somewhere. Therefore, I would question the usefulness of an 'answer' such as:

*The linux /proc filesystem is actually kernel variables pretending to be a filesystem. There is nothing to save thus nothing to backup. If the system let you, you could rm -rf /proc and it would magically reappear upon the next reboot.*

...on the grounds that it doesn't answer the question, makes a false assertion, and contains gratuitous information irrelevant to the question.